# Spring: Omit CSRF token for GET forms?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Using spring-security-web 3.2.x  (old client code), is there a way to not inject the csrf token parameter into forms that use the GET method?

That makes the token to appear in the URL when the form is submitted and which can be leaked.

Config is:

```
<http>
    <csrf>
```

JSP is:

```
<form:form method="GET" ...
```

Resulting HTML:

```
    <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value="********-****-****-****-******" />
</form>
```

Note that using:

```
<csrf request-matcher-ref="csrfMatcher"/>
```

Does not help, as this only controls whether the csrf token is checked when the form is submitted and not whether the csrf hidden field is injected into the form. (GET request are not checked anyway by default).

Answer (score 0):

There is code in CsrfRequestDataValueProcessor.java that should omit the CSRF token for GET forms:

```
private Pattern DISABLE_CSRF_TOKEN_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?i)^(GET|HEAD|TRACE|OPTIONS)$");

public String processAction(HttpServletRequest request, String action, String method) {
    if(method != null && DISABLE_CSRF_TOKEN_PATTERN.matcher(method).matches()) {
        request.setAttribute(DISABLE_CSRF_TOKEN_ATTR, Boolean.TRUE);
    } else {
        request.removeAttribute(DISABLE_CSRF_TOKEN_ATTR);
    }
    return action;
}
```

But according to both code inspection and debugging it is never called. Probably a bug.

This is spring-security-web-3.2.7 and spring-webmvc-3.2.13